# Hibernate OneToMany List mapping issue

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I have two tables as created below.

```
TableOne
   id pk
   code varchar (references a column in TableTwo, non unique)

TableTwo
   id pk
   code varchar (referenced in TableOne, non unique)
   option
```

In Table 1, one id can have only one code. In Table 2, codes can repeat for different option. i.e code + option will be unique (not that I have defined the constraint in DB).

Now, I have my entity classes as described below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableOne")
public class Table1 {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private String id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table1", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<Table2> table2s;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableTwo")
public class Table2 {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private String id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "code", referencedColumnName = "code", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Table1 table1;
}
```

When I try to execute my application, it gives following error

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Found shared references to a collection: model.Table1.table2s; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: model.Table1.table2s
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at au.th.api.assessment.service.MasterQuestionsServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e50ce6a4.getQuestionById(<generated>) [classes/:na]
```

There are two rows in TableOne that has same code. TableTwo has only one row with that code.

Can some one please help here?

**EDIT:**

If I remove **referencedColumnName**, it works fine, but the list is empty.

On debugging, I can see the list object is fetched as PersistentBag before transaction is committed. On commit, it throws above exception. The error printed before the exception is

```
o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: model.Table1.table2s]
```

Comment: What is the name of your tables? `Table2` or `TableTwo`?

Comment: @KenrySanchez, you are quick. ;-). I have edited my question to correct it.

Comment: if you change `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "table1", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` for    `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "TableTwo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: Hibernate shows that error when you attempt to persist more than one entity instance sharing the same collection reference. You are persistent TableOne twice in the same entity

Comment: It throws exception on application startup `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: model.Table2.table2 in model.Table1.table2s`

Comment: Interesting. On debugging, I see that list has values but it is of type **PersistentBag* and not list. May be there is a way to convert this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake about the OneToMany relationship. Please see the example below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course  implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private Set<Student> students;

    public Course(){ 
    }     

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private Course course;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
}
```

You can find the working example from the post [OneToMany relationship](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example.html)

Comment: Well, in my case **code** is not a primary key. I need to map non primary key.